# Referencing Predefined Device Tree Node with No Label in another File

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, device-tree

Hello I have a device tree that looks like this. I need to reference the dma@40400000 node in another file where this device tree is included. In this device tree the dma@40400000 node does not have a label.

device-tree1.dtsi

```
/dts-v1/;
/ {
    amba_pl {
    #address-cells = <0x1>;
    #size-cells = <0x1>;
    compatible = "simple-bus";
    ranges;

    dma@40400000 {
        #dma-cells = <0x1>;
        clock-names = "s_axi_lite_aclk", "m_axi_sg_aclk", "m_axi_mm2s_aclk", "m_axi_s2mm_aclk";
        clocks = <0x1 0xf 0x1 0xf 0x1 0xf 0x1 0xf>;
        compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-1.00.a";
        interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
        interrupts = <0x0 0x1d 0x4 0x0 0x1e 0x4>;
        reg = <0x40400000 0x10000>;
        xlnx,addrwidth = <0x20>;

        dma-channel@40400000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-mm2s-channel";
            dma-channels = <0x1>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x1d 0x4>;
            xlnx,datawidth = <0x20>;
            xlnx,device-id = <0x0>;
        };

        dma-channel@40400030 {
            compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-s2mm-channel";
            dma-channels = <0x1>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x1e 0x4>;
            xlnx,datawidth = <0x20>;
            xlnx,device-id = <0x0>;
        };
    };
};
};
```

I would like to redefine it or optionally the amba_pl node such that the node dma@40400000 is not changed but has a label axi_dma

device-tree2.dtsi

```
/include/ "device-tree1.dtsi"
/ {
&amba_pl {  
        axi_dma: dma@40400000 {
            #dma-cells = <0x1>;
            clock-names = "s_axi_lite_aclk", "m_axi_sg_aclk", "m_axi_mm2s_aclk", "m_axi_s2mm_aclk";
            clocks = <0x1 0xf 0x1 0xf 0x1 0xf 0x1 0xf>;
            compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-1.00.a";
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x1d 0x4 0x0 0x1e 0x4>;
            reg = <0x40400000 0x10000>;
            xlnx,addrwidth = <0x20>;

            dma-channel@40400000 {
                compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-mm2s-channel";
                dma-channels = <0x1>;
                interrupts = <0x0 0x1d 0x4>;
                xlnx,datawidth = <0x20>;
                xlnx,device-id = <0x0>;
            };

            dma-channel@40400030 {
                compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-s2mm-channel";
                dma-channels = <0x1>;
                interrupts = <0x0 0x1e 0x4>;
                xlnx,datawidth = <0x20>;
                xlnx,device-id = <0x0>;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

However when I try to redefine amba_pl from device-tree1.dtsi in device-tree2.dtsi, the compiler fails to parse the device tree. How can I add a label to the node dma@40400000 from device-tree1.dtsi?

**UPDATE**

Having looked through the spec, I want to reword my question.
How can I add a phandle to a node that is included from a different dtsi file or reference the node without a phandle?

Comment: FYI per the Devicetree specification: *"The name of include files should end with **“.dtsi”**."*, and not **.dts** as you have.  See https://www.devicetree.org/specifications/

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is perfectly possible (I just tested it, just in case). If you are having a compiler error, my guess is that there is a syntax error.

Two notes before continuing: 1) perhaps you should consider update your question showing the full dtc compiler error. 2) keep in mind @sawdust comment about both files being .dtsi suffixed.

Now, about your error. I'm only guessing but it seems your are mixing phandles are "full path" references.

#### Your pasted dtsi, which is wrong

```
/include/ "device-tree1.dtsi"
/ {
    &amba_pl { /* wrong, amba_pl is not a phandle, can't use & */
        axi_dma: dma@40400000 {
        /* properties here */

        dma-channel@40400000 {
          /* blah */
        };
      };
    };
};
```

#### Correct

```
/include/ "device-tree1.dtsi"
/ {
    amba_pl {
        axi_dma: dma@40400000 {

            /* properties here */

            dma-channel@40400000 {
                /* blah */
            };
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: I'm also referencing nodes without labels in included `dtsi` files (just simple redefinitions). I'm using that syntax to access the node: `&{/backlight} { /* foo */ };`